# Try to link Stripe account but getting the error with live key - "You must update your Connect branding settings ..."

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I want to create stripe account and link to access Stripe-hosted applications, such as Connect Onboarding. It is working fine with test key. But it is showing following error with live key. Account is created successfully. Error is giving from 'stripe.accountLinks'. Settings is optional according stripe documents. I have added after getting errors but still it is showing following errors.

**"You must update your Connect branding settings with business name, icon, brand color in order to create an account link. You can set the missing fields at [https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/connect"](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/connect%22)**

My code is given below.
Create account:

```
  

    // https://stripe.com/docs/file-upload
    
      const fplogo = fs.readFileSync('public/assets/businesses/logo.png');
      const fpicon = fs.readFileSync('public/assets/businesses/icon.png');
      const icon = await stripe.files.create({
              file: {
                data: fpicon,
                name: 'icon.png',
                type: 'application.octet-stream',
              },
              purpose: 'business_icon',
            });

     const logo = await stripe.files.create({
          file: {
            data: fplogo,
            name: 'logo.png',
            type: 'application.octet-stream',
          },
          purpose: 'business_logo',
        });

        // https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create

        const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
          country: 'US',
          type: 'standard',
          email:  user_test.user.email,
          business_profile:{
            name:  user_test.user.first_name,
            support_email: user_test.user.email,
            support_phone: user_test.user.phone_number
          },
          business_type: "company",
          settings: {
            branding :{
              icon: icon.id,
              logo: logo.id,
              primary_color: "#09aed3",
              secondary_color: "#092027"
            }
          }
        }); 
    
    // Account link
    // https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links
    
       const link = stripe.accountLinks
      .create({
        type: "account_onboarding",
        account: accountID,
        refresh_url: `${origin}/stripe/refresh/${user_id}`,
        return_url: `${origin}/stripe/success/${user_id}`,
      })
      .then((link) => link);
```

If someone could help me to get a solution, that would be awesome.

Comment: As the error says, you have to go to https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/connect (while logged into your main platform account) and set up some branding!

Comment: Thank you. It is working now.

Comment: @karllekko I can't find this setting